# K Means algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, k-means

I have imported a csv file named "Income_details" to pandas data frame. While scaling the data I am getting some error. The code and the error is posted below. Can anyone help me on this?

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df=pd.read_csv("income_detail.csv")
df.head()
plt.scatter(df['Age'], df['Income($)'])


km= KMeans(n_clusters=2)
km


y_predicted=km.fit_predict(df[['Age', 'Income($)']])
y_predicted
df['cluster']=y_predicted
df.head()
df1=df[df.cluster==0]
df2=df[df.cluster==1]
plt.scatter(df1['Age'],df1['Income($)'],color='green')
plt.scatter(df2['Age'],df2['Income($)'],color='red')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.xlabel('Income($)')
plt.legend()



scaler= MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(df[['Income($)']])
df['Income($)']=scaler.transform(df['Income($)'])
scaler.fit(df.Age)
df.Age=scaler.transform(df.Age)
df
```

For the last part, the data is not getting scaled. I am getting the following error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-abcb643c0619> in <module>()
      1 scaler= MinMaxScaler()
      2 scaler.fit(df[['Income($)']])
----> 3 df['Income($)']=scaler.transform(df['Income($)'])
      4 scaler.fit(df.Age)
      5 df.Age=scaler.transform(df.Age)

G:\New folder\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in transform(self, X)
    365         check_is_fitted(self, 'scale_')
    366 
--> 367         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    368 
    369         X *= self.scale_

G:\New folder\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    439                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    440                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 441                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    442             array = np.atleast_2d(array)
    443             # To ensure that array flags are maintained

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[60000. 70000. 40000. 20000. 23000. 45000. 46000. 67000. 32000. 22000.
 34000. 56000. 58000. 86000. 39000. 65000. 53000. 25000. 34000. 21000.
 51000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Do you have an extra pair of `[[]]` here in `scaler.fit(df[['Income($)']])`?

Comment: @Matt - Thanks! It worked after adding scaler.transform(df[['income']])